# Setting Java generics of iterators

Tags: java, generics, for-loop, iterator

I've noticed something funny Java does (or at least Netbeans) when I use classes implementing `ArrayList` and changing the generics type of the elements. I basically created an abstract class that extends `ArrayList` and some subclasses that are supposed to work with `String` objects (so something like `ArrayList<String>`). One of the things I did to try to achieve that was this:

```
public abstract class A extends ArrayList {
   ...
}
@Override
public abstract class B extends A {
   public Iterator<String> iterator() {
      return super.iterator();
   }
}
```

Another one was this:

```
public abstract class A extends ArrayList {
   ...
}
public abstract class B<String> extends A {
   @Override
   public Iterator<String> iterator() {
      return super.iterator();
   }
}
```

The first one overrides successfully the `iterator()` method assigning a String value to it. The other one somehow cancels out the type casting. The funny thing is that none of them works when it comes to for loops. This receives type `Object` instead of `String`.

```
for (String s : B) {
   ...
}
```

Do you have any idea why this happens and how can I fix it without implementing my own iterator?

Comment: In general you should [favor composition over inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance) ([Effective Java, Item 16](http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA81&lpg=PA81&dq=favor+composition+over+inheritance+effective+java&source=bl&ots=yYEfOms-O4&sig=AzKrW2db1sgCyjTP_u1F2B8P_cY&hl=en&ei=rQ64TubcAuH74QTF_qjkAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CDkQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q&f=false)). Why are you extending `ArrayList` in the first place?

Comment: You mean that in that for loop s is of type Object instead of String?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do but if I understand correctly you want a class that extends ArrayList and has a Generic type of String...  Perhaps you are looking for this:

```
public abstract class A<T> extends ArrayList<T> {
    ...
}
public abstract class B extends A<String> {
    ...
}
```

Then in your code, this:

```
B myList = ...;
for ( String s : myList ) {
    ...
}
```

Will work just fine.  Though I think you could come up with a much better solution.  Do you have more specifics about your problem?

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was trying to do. What would you recommend using instead, though?

Comment: @Aleksandar, I guess I just dont understand what the _abstract_ base class (`A` in this example) is used for.  Can you expand on this?

Answer (score 1):

Use composition instead of Inheritance

```
    public class A implements Iterable<String>{
        List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
        //do operations on myList
        public Iterator<String> iterator() {
             return myList.iterator();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you extend generic class you should care about generics. I mean that your declaration should look like

```
public abstract class A extends ArrayList<String> {
   ...
}
```

if you want to use strings or

```
public abstract class <T> A extends ArrayList<T> {
   ...
}
```

if you want  your class to be generic.

In both cases you do not have to override `iterator()` method: you can invoke its from super class and it will return you "good" iterator. Your declaration is equivalent to

```
public abstract class A extends ArrayList<Object> {
   ...
}
```

This is the reason for "strange" behavior.

BTW may I ask you why are you extending `ArrayList`? It really sounds strange.

Answer (score 0):

OMG this is terrible:

```
public abstract class B<String> extends A {
   @Override
   public Iterator<String> iterator() {
      return super.iterator();
   }
}
```

`String` is not the class `String`, rather, you are declaring a new type variable called `String` (like `T`) that shadows the class `String`